# Django app - deploy using UWSGI or Phusion Passenger

Tags: python, django, deployment, passenger, uwsgi

Which way of deploying Django app is better (or maybe the better question would be what are pros and cons):

- using UWSGI,
- using Phusion Passenger?

In my particular case the most important advantage for using Passenger is ease of use (on my hosting I need to place single file in project directory and it's done), but what with performance things, etc.?
What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Production performance is pretty the same, so I wouldn't worry about that. uWSGI has some advanced builtin features like clustering and a cron API while Phusion Passenger is more minimalist, but Phusion Passenger provides more friendly tools for administration and inspection (e.g. passenger-status, passenger-memory-stats, passenger-config system-metrics).